# How to toggle between multiple CSS preserving the changes made with previous CSS?

Tags: html, css, epub.js

[image]

I am making an epub reader with epub.js, and I intend to give a choice to toggle between various styles. 
Lets say I want to read the book in dark mode and at a smaller size, so I would first select Dark Mode CSS and then I would select a desired Font Size, but the problem I am facing is that it always picks up the latest style and removes off the previous style. In the above case it scrapes off Dark Mode and just changes the font. 
**Expected** : Dark Mode with smaller font
**Actual** : Small Font with dark mode removed.
Not only this but I would like to preserve all the previous styles that the user gave and the user should be able to choose a combination of styles.
My JS code that applies style looks like this:

```
document.getElementById("darkTheme").addEventListener("click", function(){
    rendition.themes.register("dark", "themes.css");
    rendition.themes.select("dark");
});
```

Here `dark` is a class that contains dark background and `rendition.themes.select` selects the class and applies the style present in that class and similarly I have created other classes for various different styles.

Comment: If I understand "themes" - you can't have more than one theme at once.  So either dark or small font.  I don't think trying to accomplish this via themes is the right approach.

Comment: Can you suggest a better approach to achieve the same?

Comment: A more low-level CSS approach, so you'd define a class "small-font", and then a class "dark", and you'd be able to set your elements to use `class='dark small-font'` to combine them.

Comment: I would apply the dark class on the main container , then background and color   can be inherited.